# ajax post to App Engine not working

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

So I have this html/js trying to test an ajax post

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            document.write("booo");
            var data = {"lat":5};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/geo",
                    data: data,
                });
            });
            var data = {"lat":5};
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/geo",
                    data: data,
                });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input name="lat" type="text">
        <input name="lon" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now I'm just trying to post data, pick it up in python and write it back/store it in db but nothing is happening from my ajax post function. Here's my python,

```
class GeoHandler(Handler):

    def get(self):
        self.render("geo.html")

    def post(self):
        lat = self.request.get("lat")
        lon = self.request.get("lon")
        self.write(lat)
        loc = models.LocModel(coords = db.GeoPt(lat,lon), hm = str(lat).join(str(lon)))
        loc.put()
```

My url handler is

```
    ('/geo', GeoHandler),
```

Eventually i'm trying to use javascript to capture location data of my users and map it... but app engine/webapp2 only likes to grab the ipv6 of the client and there's no way to get the location data of an ipv5 but there are html5/js solns for geo data.. but i can't even post basic data to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including the `"lon"` in the data. Something like this:

```
 var data = {"lat": 5, "lon": 6}
```

You might also want to take a look n the [Request Headers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Request_Headers) and more specifically on `X-AppEngine-CityLatLong`. It's a city level and of course it depends on your app.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Why do I need to worry about request headers i just want the data in string/float format so i can store it..?

Comment: Ohhh... I see, you're saying let app engine read the coordinate/geo data for me instead of using javascript!! At least that's what I'm seeing reading request headers link you provided...

Comment: @user772401 Yes, it really depends on the app.. but at least now you know that you have that as an option